# Apple Pay, Can we use one merchant id for multiple apps?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

We are building one e-commerce project with multiple targets(apps), my question is can we use one merchant id for all of our apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To enable your app to use Apple Pay, register an identifier with Apple that uniquely identifies your business as a merchant able to accept payments. **This ID** never expires, and **can be used in multiple websites and apps.**

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/setting_up_apple_pay